# UNIX/solaris shell script shebang in include file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh, solaris

I have a functions.sh script with a bunch of global functions that i want to use in other scripts. this functions script is written in bash (#!/bin/bash)

Those many scripts had been written over the years, so the older ones or with the #!/bin/sh (which is different from #!/bin/bash in solaris).

My question here is, when you call the functions.sh file (with . /path/to/functions.sh) from within a sh (not bash) script, is the shebang line of "functions.sh" interpreted ?

In a nutshell, can you call a bash written function script from another shell-type script (with proper shebang lines in both) ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you want to use the function you need to *source* the scripts and not *execute* it

```
source /path/to/functions.sh
```

or as per the `POSIX` standards, do

```
. ./path/to/functions.sh
```

from within the `sh` script, which is equivalent to including the contents of function.sh in the file at the point where the command is run.

You need to understand the difference between sourcing and executing a script.

- *Sourcing* runs the script from the parent-shell in which the script is
  invoked; all the environment variables, functions are retained until the
  parent-shell is terminated (the terminal is closed, or the variables
  are reset or unset),
- *Execute* forks a new shell from the parent shell and those variables,functions
  including your export variables are retained only in the sub-shell's
  environment and destroyed at the end of script termination.

Comment: Thank you Inian, just tried with using "source" and it's now working like a charm. I didn't fully understood the difference between sourcing and executing !

Comment: @seb: Happy to help!

Comment: FYI, `source` is a bashism. For POSIX sh compatibility, it does need to be `.` -- see spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_18

Comment: (also, an exec'd process that happens to be a shell is not a subshell; a subshell is, by definition, a shell created by a `fork()` with no `exec()` call following: If there's an execve, then non-exported parent state is no longer present; having read-only access to such state is one of the hallmarks of a subshell).

Answer (score 1):

When you source a file, the shebang in that file is ignored (it is not on the first line since it is included in the caller script and is seen as comment).
When you include an old script with `#!/bin/sh` it will be handled as the shell of the caller. Most things written in `/bin/sh` will work in `bash`.
When you are running a sh or ksh script and you include (`source`) a bash file, all bash specific code will give problems.